# Deploying Spring Web Applicaiton To JBoss WebApplicationContext Exceptions

Tags: java, spring, servlets, jboss

When deploying a Spring Web Application to JBoss 7.1.1, gives the following Exception:

```
12:26:58,053 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/i]] (MSC service thread 1-3) Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class com.listener.IListener: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No WebApplicationContext found: no ContextLoaderListener registered?
at org.springframework.web.context.support.WebApplicationContextUtils.getRequiredWebApplicationContext(WebApplicationContextUtils.java:84) [spring-web-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar:3.0.6.RELEASE]
at com.listener.IListener.contextInitialized(IListener.java:28) [classes:]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.contextListenerStart(StandardContext.java:3392) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:3850) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.start(WebDeploymentService.java:90) [jboss-as-web-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811)
at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886) [rt.jar:1.6.0_26]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908) [rt.jar:1.6.0_26]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662) [rt.jar:1.6.0_26]

12:26:58,115 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext] (MSC service thread 1-3) Error listenerStart
12:26:58,115 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext] (MSC service thread 1-3) Context [/i] startup failed due to previous errors
12:26:58,131 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-3) MSC00001: Failed to start service jboss.web.deployment.default-host./i: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.web.deployment.default-host./i: JBAS018040: Failed to start context
at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.start(WebDeploymentService.java:95)
at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886) [rt.jar:1.6.0_26]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908) [rt.jar:1.6.0_26]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662) [rt.jar:1.6.0_26]

12:26:58,146 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (MSC service thread 1-7) JBAS015951: Admin console listening on http://127.0.0.1:9990
12:26:58,146 ERROR [org.jboss.as] (MSC service thread 1-7) JBAS015875: JBoss AS 7.1.1.Final "Brontes" started (with errors) in 4883ms - Started 225 of 304 services (2 services failed or missing dependencies, 76 services are passive or on-demand)
12:26:58,365 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) JBAS015870: Deploy of deployment "webchannel.war" was rolled back with failure message {"JBAS014671: Failed services" => {"jboss.web.deployment.default-host./i" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service     jboss.web.deployment.default-host./i: JBAS018040: Failed to start context"}}
12:26:58,521 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBAS015877: Stopped deployment webchannel.war in 161ms
 12:26:58,521 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) JBAS014774: Service status report
JBAS014777:   Services which failed to start:      service jboss.web.deployment.default-host./i: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.web.deployment.default-host./i: JBAS018040: Failed to start context

   12:26:58,536 ERROR [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) {"JBAS014653: Composite operation failed and was rolled back. Steps that failed:" => {"Operation step-2" => {"JBAS014671: Failed services" => {"jboss.web.deployment.default-host./i" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.web.deployment.default-host./i: JBAS018040: Failed to start context"}}}}
```

I have a ServletContextListener called IListener. When I try to access the WebApplicationContext I receive the above Exception. However, this works in TomEE.

Below is the code:

```
public class IListener implements ServletContextListener {

public IListener() {

}

public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent event) {
    ServletContext context = event.getServletContext();
    WebApplicationContext webApplicationContext = WebApplicationContextUtils.getRequiredWebApplicationContext(context);
    }

public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent event) {

}
  }
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
         version="2.5">

```
     <display-name>JEE WebApp</display-name>

     <context-param>
        <!-- Specifies the list of Spring Configuration files in comma separated format.-->
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
        /WEB-INF/spring/services.xml</param-value>
     </context-param>

     <listener>
        <!-- Loads your Configuration Files-->
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
        <listener-class>com.listener.IListener</listener-class>
     </listener>

     <servlet>
        <servlet-name>i</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
     </servlet>

     <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>i</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
     </servlet-mapping>

     <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
     </welcome-file-list>
```

Java version is 1.6 and Spring version 3.0.6.RELEASE.

I am not sure what to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually, the `ContextLoaderListener` from Spring is good to go. If you don't have any specific requirements, just use that one. All-in-all, it should look like this:

```
 <listener>
    <!-- Loads your Configuration Files-->
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
 </listener>
```

If you need to have a listener that uses the Spring context, you could consider extending this class. Make sure that the `contextInitialized()` method calls the `super` implementation first (so that it can initialize the Spring context for you). Afterwards, it will be available through `(WebApplicationContext) servletContext.getAttribute(WebApplicationContext.ROOT_WEB_APPLICATION_CONTEXT_ATTRIBUTE)`. Your `contextDestroyed()` method, however, should first do its own logic and finally call its super implementation.

Note, however, that this is not a very clean solution from the ["seperation of concerns"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns) point of view.

My recommendation would be, if possible, to use Spring filters, listeners or [Interceptors](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-handlermapping-interceptor). They are autowired automatically by Spring and you can use the full Spring power inside them.

Comment: Actually, I have a requirement to have my own listener.

Comment: I can see from the logs that the event.getServletContext() works. It is only when WebApplicationContext webApplicationContext = WebApplicationContextUtils.getRequiredWebApplicationContext(context) that gives the problem.

Comment: And your listener needs to initialize the Spring context itself? Or could you build an [`ApplicationListener`](http://learningviacode.blogspot.nl/2012/07/spring-and-events-and-listeners.html), for example?

Comment: The listener needs to initialize the Spring context itself.