# Exception in JSF Programe Using JBoss 7.1.1 final

Tags: java, xml, spring, jsf-2, jboss

When ever i edit my web.xml file in JSF application after editing the wed.xml file the JBoss server will throw the exception

```
 org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.web.deployment.default-host./shop: JBAS018040: Failed to start context
```

i dont know why it occurs every time when i delete web.xml and create again then the JBoss never throws Exception and if i again edit web.xml fine it will throws the same exception until unless i will delete the file and create again...

i also visit this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17810811/deploying-spring-web-applicaiton-to-jboss-webapplicationcontext-exceptions) but it is not helpfull for me

Comment: Are you using Spring and JSF?

Comment: This is a generic detail message of `JBoss` when your `WAR` file not deployed properly. I assume there should some other Exception causing `WAR` file to fail to deploy. Did you check your `IDE` console for any other excepitons?